# Binding multiple files input data to data model in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML View:

```
<form>
        <input type="file" file-input="files" multiple/>
      <button ng-click="initUpload()">Upload</button>
</form>
```

I have borrowed the following directive (to bind multiple file type input) from variety of answers I found on this website:

```
module.directive('fileInput', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link:function(scope, elm, attrs){
         var model = $parse(attrs.fileInput);
         var isMultiple = attrs.multiple;
         var modelSetter = model.assign;
         elm.bind('change', function(){
            var values =[];
            angular.forEach(elm[0].files, function(item){
              var value = {
                name: item.name,
                  type: item.type,
                  _file: item
              };
              values.push(value);

            });

            scope.$apply(function(){
               if(isMultiple){
                   modelSetter(scope, values);
               } else{
                   modelSetter(scope, values[0]);
               }
            });
         });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Bottomline question is: In the controller, how will I access the array of files? Currently I am trying to access them using `$scope.values[i]`, but that is not working.

If i try to find the number of files uploaded, I thought `$scope.values.length` should ideally work?

What am I missing here?

Comment: set the files on the parent scope (the scope of the controller)

Comment: Please you can use this for image uploading best that i have seen https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-upload

Comment: @PankajSharma question says multiple file type input

Comment: yes i see that but you just check demo of that link you will get your answer. this library includes all file uploading solution.

Comment: @Bowofola : Noob Alert: can u explain me how to set files on the parent scope? I thought thats what we were doing when we did this: `modelSetter(scope, values);`

Comment: @PankajSharma thanks for alerting me to this solution. Will look this lib up for future use.

Comment: I was referring to `scope.$parent` but now that I look at it you dont have an isolated scope so that should be the scope of your controller. But to confirm, set a some test property on your controller scope. set breakpoint on modelSetter, and see if the property is on scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with same scope directive. You can achieve this as below.

```
app.directive('fileInput', function() {
  return {
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.on('change', function(event) {
        scope[attr.fileInput] = event.target.files;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/agabhane/pen/EmdbwX)